# Whats the most efficient way of adding milliseconds to this code?

Tags: perl, time, timestamps

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Get time string
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
sub formatTime
    {
    my ( $seconds )  = @_;

    my( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) =
                                localtime( $seconds );
    $year += 1900;
    $mon += 1;

    return ( sprintf "%02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d:%02d",
                $mday,$mon,$year,$hour,$min,$sec );
    }

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Extract time from the string
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
sub extractTime
    {
    my ( $edate, $time ) = @_;

    my $date =  $1 if ($edate =~ /(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)/);    # remove leading '[' etc.
    my ( $mday, $mon, $year ) = split( /\//, $date );
    my ( $hour,$min, $sec ) = split( /:/, $time );

    return (timelocal( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, ($mon - 1), ($year - 1900 )));
    }
```

Comment: The callers of these functions will need to change. Eg whatever calls `formatTime()` will need to pass in milliseconds rather than seconds. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @jordanm The script is actually pretty big, all I did was modify the date to include nano seconds %N, but it really didnt, I cant see anything to add along with what calls formatTime() that would help without changing the above

Comment: Please see [ask]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to to get a higher precision for you function `formatTime`, you need to take in miliseconds, rather than seconds. You can't take rounded seconds and make it more precise.

Since localtime() only accepts seconds since epoch, you will need to convert the miliseconds passed in and convert it to seconds. Here is an example:

```
use POSIX qw(floor);

sub formatTime {
    my ( $milliseconds )  = @_;

    my $seconds = floor($milliseconds / 1000);
    my $msec = $milliseconds % 1000;

    my( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) =
                                localtime( $seconds );
    $year += 1900;
    $mon += 1;

    return ( sprintf "%02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d:%02d:%04d",
                $mday,$mon,$year,$hour,$min,$sec,$msec );
}
```

The other option would be to use the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.78/lib/DateTime.pm). If you pass in seconds as a decimal, it can create a DateTime object with greater precision:

```
use DateTime;

sub formatTime {
    my ( $seconds ) = @_;
    my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $seconds );
    # ....
}
```

Comment: I tried both options with a bit of tweaks and managed to get millisecond timestamp for both, Thanks.